# I am using ckeditor online builder for react. but it not generating html attributes

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

[This how it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvq4z.jpg)

This is my code. I used ckeditor online builder. in editor everything shows corrects. but when i check the console. it's not generating html tags.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import  styled from 'styled-components';

import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'




const Ckeditor = () => {


  const [content, setContent] = useState("")

  const handleCkEditor = (event, editor)=>{
    const data = editor.getData()
    console.log(data)
  }


return (
    <Container>
      <CKEditor
        editor={ Editor }
          
          onReady={ editor => {
          // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
          console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
          } }

          onChange={handleCkEditor}
          onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
            console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
          } }
          onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
            console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
          } }
          onInit={editor => {
            window.editor = editor;
          }}
          
      />
    </Container>
)
```

}

export default Ckeditor